# Sorting Firebase data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm making a simple todo app with ReactJS and Firebase and I want to sort my todos by the time they were made. I get that I need to use server timestamps, but can't figure out a way to implement sorting to my way of displaying Firebase data. This is how I fetch the data:

```
useEffect(() => {
      const getTodos = async() => {
        const data = await getDocs(todosRef);
        setNewTodos(data.docs.map((doc) => ({...doc.data(), id: doc.id})))
      }
      getTodos();
    }, [])
```

And this how I add new todos to the database:

```
await addDoc(todosRef, {
      text: input,
      dueDate: date,
      comments: [],
      //timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
    });
    setInput('');
    window.location.reload();
  }
```

Plus, when I try to add the new todo with the timestamp nothing happends. It won't push it to the database, so that's why it's commented out.

Comment: I sorted out the timestamp problem. I don't know how to write the query and where to put it. I only saw the sorting in play when using the snapshot method.

Comment: You just need to write the query inside getTodos function instead of just getting todos collection you apply the query (orderBy timestamp) and use getDocs on that selected query.

Answer (score 1):

For serverTimestamp you can just directly import it in modular v9.

import { addDoc, serverTimestamp } from "firebase/firestore";

```
await addDoc(todosRef, {
    timestamp: serverTimestamp()
 })
```

As for timestamp sorting you can simply generate a query and order by timestamp descending.

```
const q = query(todosRef, orderBy("timestamp", "desc");
const data = await getDocs(q);
```

Comment: Thank you alot! I've been struggling for so long. I have to keep in mind that im using v9 now.

Comment: Cheers. Please accept this answer if it was useful!